# YouTube Auto-Like script not working until I refresh

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

I am not the author of the code and have no prior experience with code, the credits go to the original author, JoeSimmons. So the problem I am having is the code works fine, but it only works when I either refresh the YouTube video page or I go to the link directly, like from a Google search. I'd like to know if anyone would be able to help me out in fixing the issue. Of course, i'm not experienced at all with even the simplest of scripts. Thankyou in advance! I apologise if the tagging on the question is wrong, as I said earlier i'm clueless.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           YouTube Auto-Like Videos
// @namespace      http://userscripts.org/users/23652
// @description    Automatically clicks the 'Like' button
// @include        http://*.youtube.com/watch*v=*
// @include        http://youtube.com/watch*v=*
// @include        https://*.youtube.com/watch*v=*
// @include        https://youtube.com/watch*v=*
// @copyright      JoeSimmons
// @version        1.1.02
// @license        GPL version 3 or any later version; http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
// @require        https://greasyfork.org/scripts/1884-gm-config/code/GM_config.js?version=4836
// @require        https://greasyfork.org/scripts/1885-joesimmons-library/code/JoeSimmons'%20Library.js?version=7915
// @require        https://greasyfork.org/scripts/2104-youtube-button-container-require/code/YouTube%20-%20Button%20Container%20(@require).js?version=5493
// @grant          GM_getValue
// @grant          GM_setValue
// @grant          GM_registerMenuCommand
// ==/UserScript==

/* CHANGELOG

    1.1.02 (6/7/2015)
        - fixed script

    1.1.01 (3/14/2015)
        - fixed bug of it liking all videos when username list was empty

    1.1.0 (3/13/2015)
        - added a new option to allow auto-liking of videos from subscribed channels

    1.0.40 (3/12/2015)
        - adapted to YouTube changing like/dislike buttons' classes

    1.0.39 (1/26/2015)
        - changed the timeout of the script so it waits a real 30 seconds, not X amout of intervals
            should be more accurate, especially on weaker computers whose browsers freeze and the intervals overlap

    1.0.38 (1/19/2015)
        - adapted to page change (different class name of author link)

    1.0.37 (9/8/2014)
        - adapted to new YouTube style
        - fixed an issue with channel names with punctuation in them not getting "liked"

    1.0.36 (12/17/2013)
        - added a user-script command for the options

    1.0.35 (12/14/2013)
        - started using YouTube Button Container
        - made code more readable by using JSL and @requires

    1.0.34
        - added compatibility for Opera & Chrome

*/



(function () {
    'use strict';

    var t = 0, tMax = 30,
        spaceRegex = /([ \t]+)|(\n[ \r\n\r]+\n)/g,
        newlineRegex = /\n/g,
        uRegex = /\/user\/(\w+)/i,
        spaces = /\s+/g,
        rBlank = /^\s*$/,
        rVideoId = /[&?]v=([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/,
        rSubscribed = /^true$/i,
        rUnclicked = /like-button-renderer-(dis)?like-button-unclicked/,
        intv, pass, auto_like_list, timeStart, likeSubscribedChannels;

    // click by JoeSimmons
    function click(element, type) {
        var eventObject = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
            element = typeof element === 'string' ? document.getElementById(element) : element;
            type =  typeof type === 'string' ? type : 'click';

        if (element.isJSL === true) {
            element = element[0];
        }

        if (element) {
            eventObject.initMouseEvent(type, true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            element.dispatchEvent(eventObject);
        }
    }

    function waitForShare() {
        var shareBox = JSL('#watch-action-panels'),
            shareCloseButton = JSL('#action-panel-dismiss');

        // close the Share box after it appears
        if (shareBox.visible) {
            window.setTimeout(click, 750, shareCloseButton);
        } else {
            window.setTimeout(waitForShare, 250);
        }
    }

    function isPressed(e) {
        return e.attribute('class').match(rUnclicked) == null;
    }

    function doLike() {
        var author = JSL('#watch7-user-header .yt-user-info a.g-hovercard'),
            like = JSL('#watch8-sentiment-actions button.like-button-renderer-like-button'),
            dislike = JSL('#watch8-sentiment-actions button.like-button-renderer-dislike-button'),
            subBox = JSL('#watch7-subscription-container span .yt-uix-subscription-button'),
            authorHref = '',
            authorText = '',
            usernameHref = '',
            usernameText = '';

        // quit trying to auto-like after 15 seconds
        if ( (Date.now() - timeStart) >  15000) {
            JSL.clearInterval(intv);
            // throw new Error('Warning: 30 seconds elapsed; failed to auto-like video id: ' + window.location.href.match(rVideoId)[1] );
        }

        // check if author link, like button, or sub box don't exist
        if (!author.exists || !like.exists || !subBox.exists) {
            throw new Error('Error: Either the Author link, Like button, or Sub Box does not exist.');
        }

        // grab the author text and href
        authorText = author.text();
        authorHref = author.prop('href');

        // figure out the username of the video author
        if ( authorHref.match(uRegex) ) {
            usernameHref = authorHref.match(uRegex)[1];
        }
        usernameText = authorText.replace(spaces, '');

        // try to click like
        if ( GM_config.get('auto') === true || ( auto_like_list.match(rBlank) == null && ( usernameHref.match(pass) || usernameText.match(pass) ) ) ||
               (likeSubscribedChannels === true && subBox.attribute('data-is-subscribed').match(rSubscribed) ) ) {
            if ( !isPressed(like) && !isPressed(dislike) ) {
                window.setTimeout(click, 750, like);
                JSL.clearInterval(intv);

                // if enabled, close the "share" box that appears after liking a video
                if (GM_config.get('closeShare') === true) {
                    window.setTimeout(waitForShare, 3500);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // make sure the page is not in a frame
    if (window.frameElement || window !== window.top) { return; }

    if (typeof GM_registerMenuCommand === 'function') {
        GM_registerMenuCommand('YouTube Auto-Like Options', GM_config.open);
    }

    GM_config.init('YouTube Auto-Like Options', {
        auto : {
            section : ['Main Options'],
            label : 'Auto-like ALL videos?',
            type : 'checkbox',
            'default' : true,
            title : 'Enabling this will make you "Like" all videos'
        },
        closeShare : {
            label : 'Auto-close Share Box After Liking',
            type : 'checkbox',
            'default' : false,
            title : 'Enabling this will close the Share box after the video gets "Liked"'
        },
        likeSubscribedChannels : {
            label : 'Auto-like Videos From Subscribed Channels',
            type : 'checkbox',
            'default' : false,
            title : 'If a video was uploaded by a channel you\'re subscribed to, it will like it'
        },
        list : {
            section : ['Specific Usernames'],
            label : 'List the usernames of the users\' videos you want to auto-like.',
            type : 'textarea',
            cols : 80,
            rows : 20,
            'default' : 'Write usernames here separated by lines',
            title : 'This feature will be enabled if the previous feature is disabled.'
        }
    });

    Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'prepareRegex', {
        enumerable : false,
        value : function () {
            return this.replace(/[*^&$.()?+{}|\[\]\/\\]/g, '\\$&');
        }
    });

    auto_like_list = GM_config.get('list');
    likeSubscribedChannels = GM_config.get('likeSubscribedChannels');

    // convert the list of channel names to a regular expression
    pass = new RegExp('(' + auto_like_list.trim().replace(spaceRegex, '').prepareRegex().replace(newlineRegex, '|') + ')', 'i');

    // Run a function when the page is fully loaded
    JSL.runAt('end', function() {
        addButtonToContainer('Auto-Like Options', GM_config.open);

        // try to 'like' the video for 30 seconds max
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            timeStart = Date.now();

            intv = JSL.setInterval(function () {
                doLike();
            }, 750);
        }, 1000);
    });

}());
```

Comment: When asking a question it helps to start with a brief description of what your code is trying to do so that people don't need to dig to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: The code is supposed to "Like" a YouTube video automatically when you click on the video.